# Change a UIBarButtonItem's style to a BarButtonSystemItem

Tags: iphone, ios4, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I'm new to iPhone development, so I'm not sure if it is a very common issue. I didn't find anything about this on Google.

I have a UIBarButtonItem defined with Interface Builder:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cameraButton;
```

For now, it's just a simple button, but I want to put a camera image on it, using `UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera`. I know it's possible to do it with `initWithBarButtonSystemItem`, but I there is no method like `changeWithBarButtonSystemItem`. I'd like to something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [cameraButton changeWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera];
}
```

How is it possible ? Is there a way to tell Interface Builder to instantiate directly the button with this camera icon ?

---

### Edit

It seems that it's not possible to change a button style after its instantiation. So only one question remains: Is there a way to tell Interface Builder to instantiate a button with `UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera` ?

Comment: The "this question" link appears to refer to this document. Is that intended?

Comment: Well its a bad copy-paste. Thanks for highlighting it.

Comment: Here is the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33341176/2032045

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Interface Builder, change the UIBarButtonItem's "Identifier" to "Camera."

If you need to change buttons at run-time, the easiest thing is to swap out buttons themselves, not try to mutate them.

Comment: Thanks, it worked (of course) ! Just a little precision: by "swap out", do you mean that I have to delete it and add another button as it is immutable ?

Comment: Yes. You could easily write a -replaceButton:withButton: method in a category on, e.g., UIToolbar to cleanly encapsulate this behavior, if you wanted.

Comment: That's a proper solution. Thanks !