# How to use UIBarButtonSystemItem to change UIBarButtonItem identifier? (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I want to change the identifier of an UIBarButtonItem with codes from "Play" to "Pause". How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [toggle between UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay and UIBarButtonSystemItemPause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068629/toggle-between-uibarbuttonsystemitemplay-and-uibarbuttonsystemitempause)

Comment: ho michar vu ahmed??

Comment: no it is not. I'm asking about swift.

Answer (score 18):

1) init a new button

```
//change to play
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "someAction")
navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = button

//change to pause
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "someOtherAction")
navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

2) Just change the text:

```
navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "AnyText"
```

If you're also having trouble accessing the navigation bar it is probably best to just set some tag to it (I like to use negative tags for specific Views* to make sure 2 views* don't get the same tag).
Then you could fx do like this:

```
let navigationBar = (self.view.viewWithTag(-1) as UINavigationBar)
navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "AnyText"
```

Answer (score 7):

I use this code to switch Edit mode

```
@IBAction func editMode(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.setEditing(!self.isEditing, animated: true)

    let newButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: (self.isEditing) ? .done : .edit, target: self, action: #selector(editMode(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(newButton, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For a toolbar item, here is the sample code.

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBOutlet var toolbar: UIToolbar!
@IBOutlet var playPauseButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func playPause(sender: AnyObject) {

    if player.playing {

        player.pause()

        playPauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playPause:")

        toolbar.items![0] = playPauseButton //apply for first toolbar item

    } else {

        player.play()

        playPauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "playPause:")

        toolbar.items![0] = playPauseButton //apply for first toolbar item


    }

}
```

Comment: We don't need the playPauseButton outlet reference if we have inject the item into the toolBar.

Answer (score 1):

This code is tested and working with Swift 2

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

//playToPause()
@IBAction func playButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let newBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "pauseButton:")
    navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = newBarButton
}

// pauseToPlay()
@IBAction func pauseButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    let pauseBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playButton:")
    navigationBar.topItem!.rightBarButtonItem = pauseBtnItem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw looked at several threads and this is the only answer that actually does what I'm looking for.  The only problem I have is that it moves my toolbar item to the far left, and I have it centered.  If you have your button centered with a flexible space bar, or if it is not the first button, just change the index  like this:
    `toolbar.items![1] = playPauseButton //apply for second toolbar item`