# How do I change a play button to a pause button when tapped on?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I need to change my play button to a pause button and vice versa when tapped on. I am still new to this, so I don't know how to identify buttons in the `.swift` file or how to change icons programmatically in the `.swift` file.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    var toggleState = 1

    @IBAction func playPauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if toggleState == 1 {
            player.play()
            toggleState = 2
        } else {
            player.pause()
            toggleState = 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        player.stop()
        player.currentTime = 0 
    }

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        player.volume = sliderValue.value
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("StarWars", ofType: "mp3")!
        var error: NSError?

        player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: audioPath), error: &error)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: As there only seem to be two states for `toggleState`, it might be useful to rename the property to `playerIsPlaying` (or something like that), and have it be a `Bool`.  
Or you could define an `enum` with two cases, which would replace `1` and `2` (as they are not very descriptive).

Comment: Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211993/how-to-use-uibarbuttonsystemitem-to-change-uibarbuttonitem-identifier-swift/33341176#33341176

Answer (score 10):

You can change the image of the button depending on the state:

```
@IBAction func playPauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        var playBtn = sender as UIButton
        if toggleState == 1 {
            player.play()
            toggleState = 2
            playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            player.pause()
            toggleState = 1           
            playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
```

The `sender` object passed to the `playPauseButton` is your UIButton which calls the method. Because it is sent as an object of type `AnyObject` we cast it to a `UIButton`. If you do not want to cast it, and are sure only a UIButton will call this method you can simply replace `AnyObject` with `UIButton` in the function parameter.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/playing